# Angular2 Router navigate with multiple params issue

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I'm trying to get the Angular2 new router working and I got most of it so far, except one annoying issue I can't solve.

For some reason when I use the router's `navigate` function with 2 parameters (matrix params) it will not run the subscribe code if one of the params is already populated and not changed, even if the other param changes.

Example:

```
import {ActivatedRoute, Router} from '@angular/router';
@Component({.... })

export class AnalystSearch implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
    querySubscriber: any;
    filterString:string;
    constructor(private route:ActivatedRoute, private router:Router) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.querySubscriber = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
            //Do Things
        });
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        this.querySubscriber.unsubscribe();
    }

    filter():void {

        let params:any = this.route.snapshot.params;
        params["filter"] = encodeURIComponent(this.filterString);
        params["search"] = params["search"] || "";

        this.router.navigate(["/analysts", {search: params.search, filter: params.filter}]);
    }
}
```

Usually when `filter()` is called params already contains a search value (meaning - `{search: "someRandomString"}` and the change is that I add/modify the filter attribute (so it looks like - `{search: "someRandomString", filter: "someFilterString"}` )

I can see the url changing accordingly, but the code in the `params.subscribe` isn't running!! Why??

Note that if I change the value in the `param.search` attribute it will fire the code in `params.subscribe`.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: So I set up this exact thing and it works for me.  I am using `@angular/router` version `0.2.0`.  So I do not believe it is a bug in the navigate functionality.  What triggers `filter()` to be called?  Is it a button click?  That is what I had it wired into in my example.

Comment: You may also want to take a look at [this issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/9970)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [this comment](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/9484#issuecomment-227846128) on a similar issue, it is suggested that you target the parent router to get the params.

In your case, something like

```
this.router.routerState.parent(this.route).params.subscribe(params => {...})
```

should do the trick.

I have no idea why it has to be so ugly. I expected this to work the way you did it.